# How can I take 2 as a common in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If there is a equation like this

**$2n+4$**

I do : $\;2(n+2)$

But How can I take 2 as common in this equation : $2^m+l$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, $2n = 2*n$ and $4=2*2$.

In the latter example $2^m=2*2^{m-1}$ and $l=2*\frac{l}{2}$. Now can you do it?

Comment: Look at the answer of Adi Dani..

Comment: @user1444692 Good reply... Even if one can (still) not do it, one can always look at the answer of Adi Dani ...!

Comment: But that answer gives me solution..and your's tooo

Comment: I would have thought that the current answer is just as good :) - it's not mine :)

Comment: Yes, Now I realize  that Your answer is best!!

Comment: Hahaha, you are really funny :D. I agree that this answer is beyond brilliant, but it is not mine :D

Comment: Honestly,Not Yours???

Comment: user2584283 $\neq$ user144248 $\neq$ user1444692

Comment: Sorry.. Sorry... for that...

Answer (score 2):

$$2^m+l=2\cdot2^{m-1}+2\cdot\frac{l}{2}=2\left(2^{m-1}+\frac{l}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thats What I want... ThankYou Adi

Comment: You are welcome!